# nginx Set-Cookie directive

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to modify cookies when using nginx as a reverse proxy similar to what Set-Cookie does in apache?

I have a web application that sets session cookies and I wish to append the HttpOnly flag to them before they are served by nginx. Unfortunatly I cannot modify the source code of the application to do it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/278319/how-to-rewrite-the-domain-part-of-set-cookie-in-a-nginx-reverse-proxy.  Seems to be that the same "It's not possible" and methods for resolving it apply.

Comment: didn't tried it, but I suppose that you can modify the header via http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) to add one, but even if you parse cookies coming down from backend looking at the [`http_cookie`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) variable, you won't be able to modify them using vanilla nginx.

What you could use however is the 3rd-party [Lua module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule). The link provided by Kyle Sith has an answer containg a small code snippet manipulating cookies (https://serverfault.com/a/448887/140131).

Comment: Can't you edit the header like you can with apache?