# In nginx reverse proxy, how to set the secure flag for cookies?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy to serve a https-only site. So I want the cookies for this site flagged as secure. But the backend server is an http one so it won't set the secure flag to its cookies. How can I modify the Set-Cookie header in response to add a secure flag?

Comment: Asked and answered over on SO. See SO for nginx example for Tomcat7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916906/nginx-managed-ssl-with-tomcat-7/24099526#24099526

Comment: Such an override is currently not possible, but there is an issue/ticket about `proxy_cookie_secure`: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/368

However it is not yet implemented (and the issue is old).

Comment: This third-party [module](https://github.com/AirisX/nginx_cookie_flag_module) could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get your nginx proxy modify the cookies created by the backend and set the secure flag - for inspiration see [How to rewrite the domain part of Set-Cookie in a nginx reverse proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/278319/how-to-rewrite-the-domain-part-of-set-cookie-in-a-nginx-reverse-proxy).

However I'd imagine that getting whatever is creating the cookie on the backend to set the secure flag is going to be a better solution.  How you do that is another story (or question :).

Comment: It might help you to set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header and make sure it is interpreted by your application. This is a common technique and also enables mixed http/https applications to react properly based on the protocol.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following nginx config code:

```
# make cookie secure (case sensitive)
proxy_cookie_domain ~(?P<secure_domain>([-0-9a-z]+\.)?[-0-9a-z]+\.[a-z]+)$ "$secure_domain; secure";
```

Instead of the regex to make this dynamical you can of course use the FQDN.

Comment: Is this just on response or both request and response. When the client sends a request with the secure flag set does nginx strip it so the web server doesn't complain?

Comment: Clients do not send back the secure flag in the `Cookie` header.

Answer (score 1):

This help me:

```
proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure";
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path